# Pandas.sort_index does not sort by second given argument

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Here is a MWE:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.np.random.seed(0)
(
    pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.rand(10, 5), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
    .assign(b=lambda df: (df.b*10).astype(int))
    .set_index(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    .sort_index(axis=0, level=['b', 'a'])
)

Out[96]: 
                            d         e
a        b c                           
0.087129 0 0.832620  0.778157  0.870012
0.639921 1 0.944669  0.521848  0.414662
0.670638 2 0.128926  0.315428  0.363711
0.359508 4 0.697631  0.060225  0.666767
0.645894 4 0.891773  0.963663  0.383442
0.791725 5 0.568045  0.925597  0.071036
0.617635 6 0.616934  0.943748  0.681820
0.264556 7 0.456150  0.568434  0.018790
0.978618 7 0.461479  0.780529  0.118274
0.548814 7 0.602763  0.544883  0.423655
```

I don't understand why the `a` index is not sorted (see the `b=7` rows).

Expected results (but not acceptable solution):

```
pd.np.random.seed(0)
(
    pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.rand(10, 5), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
    .assign(b=lambda df: (df.b*10).astype(int))
    .sort_values(['b', 'a'])
    .set_index(['a', 'b', 'c'])
)

Out[104]: 
                            d         e
a        b c                           
0.087129 0 0.832620  0.778157  0.870012
0.639921 1 0.944669  0.521848  0.414662
0.670638 2 0.128926  0.315428  0.363711
0.359508 4 0.697631  0.060225  0.666767
0.645894 4 0.891773  0.963663  0.383442
0.791725 5 0.568045  0.925597  0.071036
0.617635 6 0.616934  0.943748  0.681820
0.264556 7 0.456150  0.568434  0.018790
0.548814 7 0.602763  0.544883  0.423655
0.978618 7 0.461479  0.780529  0.118274
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting your multi-index you need to provide `b` as the first level of your index:

```
...
.set_index(['b', 'a', 'c'])
...
```

Output:

```
                            d           e
b   a           c       
0   0.087129    0.832620    0.778157    0.870012
1   0.639921    0.944669    0.521848    0.414662
2   0.670638    0.128926    0.315428    0.363711
4   0.359508    0.697631    0.060225    0.666767
    0.645894    0.891773    0.963663    0.383442
5   0.791725    0.568045    0.925597    0.071036
6   0.617635    0.616934    0.943748    0.681820
7   0.264556    0.456150    0.568434    0.018790
    0.548814    0.602763    0.544883    0.423655
    0.978618    0.461479    0.780529    0.118274
```

Multi-index in pandas works as a nested structure of indexes: rows are grouped first by the 1st-level index, then the 2nd-level etc.

So, when you provide `a` as your first level it tries to find other rows that have the same value (e.g. `0.264556`) in the same index level. Since, your `a`-values seem to be unique in general, each group has just one member eventually, which means there's nothing to sort in each group.

Comment: I noticed there were something with the order of the columns in index, but why is it so? Is it a bug?

Comment: I have now added an explanation for that in my reply.

Comment: but still `b` is sorted (see the `df` without sorting, `b` should be unordered)

Comment: what do you mean? `b` should be unordered in the output? Why do you provide it to the `sort_index` function then?

Comment: I don't understand your explanation. If it was like in a `groupby` then `b` would not be sorted, though it is. If I just `sort_index(['a'])` then the sort works.

Comment: Please specify again what is your end goal in your original question. Do you want to sort your data frame just based on `a`?